# How to reject randomly generated numbers in R that don't meet a criterion

Tags: r, random, while-loop, normal-distribution

In R, I'm generating random numbers from a uniform distribution, then using Marsaglia and Bray's method to transform these to random normal deviates. A step in this process is to transform `u[1]^2 + u[2]^2` to a value, `w`. This `w` can only be accepted if `w < 1`.

What can I write to reject the number if it is larger than 1? As I'm doing this inside a `while` loop, I don't want to add a count to the index for rejected values. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use a recursive function generating `2` numbers. It's more a functional programming approach than using a while loop:

```
gen = function(n=2)
{
    if(n==0) return(numeric(0))
    x = runif(1)
    y = runif(1)
    w = x**2 + y **2
    m_defect = sum(w>1)
    c(x,y,gen(m_defect))
}

#> gen()
#[1] 0.3429797 0.5950654
#> sum(gen()**2)
#[1] 0.3164518
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `x**2` over `x^2`. I have not seen this before.

Comment: Not from what I know, these are equivalent in case of `0^1, 0^0, (-1)**0.5`, I was just lazy to press Alt Gr ...